# Unable to format or use two USB flash drives

Tags: usb, usb-drive, readonly

I have 2 USB's I'm unable to use...  One went out a Month ago and the second followed suit yesterday.  The USB's are **Supersonic RAGE Elite 128GB** drives and I've tried everything I can think of through Linux & Windows.  I've tried **USB2** & **USB3** ports. Any help would be appreciated.

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdg:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly = 0 (off)

sudo fsck -f /dev/sdg
```

Disk write-protected; use the -n option to do a read-only check of the device

```
sudo wipefs -a /dev/sdg
```

probing initialization failed: Read-only file system

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg
```

dd: failed to open '/dev/sdg': Read-only file system

```
sudo -i
umount /dev/sdg
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdg
```

mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdg: Read-only file system

Answer (score 0):

*This is just a suggestion, in case you are desperate, and may not actually fix the read only issue*

---

What I use to check dodgy USB sticks is utilities (i.e. *f3probe* and *f3fix*) from the [**F3**](https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (Fight Flash Fraud] suite - on Github [AltraMayor](https://github.com/AltraMayor)/[f3](https://github.com/AltraMayor/f3). It should be able to get around your read only issue - at least to check the drive, although it might not be able to remove the lock.

Note that, when using some of the utilities, you *may* lose any data that was on the stick, so read the [documentation](https://fight-flash-fraud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) *very* carefully.

If you want to run a check on Windows, then use [**h2testw**](https://3ds.hacks.guide/h2testw-(windows).html), which does a write/read test. It works more or less the same as F3, but it isn't as configurable. However, if the stick is mounting as read only then **h2testw** might not be much use.

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot write raw data to the drive as indicated by you,

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdg
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdg': Read-only file system
```

we can conclude that the *hardware itself* is read-only. This condition is sometimes called 'gridlock', that the drive is 'gridlocked', and it is a first stage of complete failure. Save the files, if any, before the drive will be completely dead.

But there might also be confusion, so there are a few things to try before giving up on your USB drives. [This link to an answer at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) has a list of things to check and also some other tips and links.

---

You have tried some but maybe not all items in the following list:

- On some pendrives and on many memory cards there is a small mechanical switch for write protection, that can toggle between read/write and read-only. You might have set it read-only without intention.
- Reboot the computer and try again to restore or wipe the first megabyte with mkusb.
- Disconnect other USB devices. Sometimes USB devices can disturb the function for each other.
- Try other USB ports, and/or other card adapters.
- Try another computer.
- Try another operating system (Windows, MacOS) in another computer.